# Python Regular Expressions Return Floating Points

Tags: python, regex

For a project I have to extract the RGB values from a file which are defined as following:

```
#71=IFCCOLOURRGB($,0.75,0.73,0.6800000000000001);
#98=IFCCOLOURRGB($,0.26,0.22,0.18);
```

I want to retun the RGB data and write it to a new file like this:

```
0.75 0.73 0.68

0.26 0.22 0.18
```

So far I've created this for loop:

```
import re 

IfcFile = open('IfcOpenHouse.ifc', 'r')

IfcColourRGB = re.compile('ifccolourrgb', re.IGNORECASE)


for rad_rgb_data in IfcFile:
    if re.search(IfcColourRGB, rad_rgb_data):
        print(IfcColourRGB.sub('', rad_rgb_data))
```

This returns:

```
#71=($,0.75,0.73,0.6800000000000001);

#98=($,0.26,0.22,0.18);
```

Now I am quite new to programming and I want to know if I've chosen the right approach for my task, I've been reading about regular expressions but I don't fully understand how to get rid of all the #=(,: characters and how to exactly specify which numbers you want returned and which not. Is it possible to define all regular expressions explicitly/individually and combining them in one for loop so I have an easier time understanding them?

Comment: You might not need to use regex, you could just split the string on the ","

Comment: Agreed but regex have the advantage to be less specific on the formated string. I mean you can change the way you store it and don't have to change this part of the code (the reading one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this :^) You can loop through the lines and perform this search on each.

```
import re
Searcher = re.compile("IFCCOLOURRGB\(\$,([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+)")

for Line in IfcFile:
    Result = Searcher.search(Line)
    if Result:
        print Result.groups()
```

If you are just writing the values back out to a file, you don't need to convert to float after,except to truncate the `00000001` and print to 2 significant figures.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall()` with a positive look-behind pattern , then split with `,` and convert to float :

```
>>> s="""#71=IFCCOLOURRGB($,0.75,0.73,0.6800000000000001);
... #98=IFCCOLOURRGB($,0.26,0.22,0.18);"""
>>> import re
>>> l=re.findall(r'(?<=\$,)[\d\.,]+',s)
>>> [map(float,i.split(',')) for i in l]
[[0.75, 0.73, 0.68], [0.26, 0.22, 0.18]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the colors use:

```
IFCCOLOURRGB\((?P<Red>\.[0-9]{1,16}|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,16})?),(?P<Green>\.[0-9]{1,16}|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,16})?),(?P<Blue>\.[0-9]{1,16}|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,16})?)\)
```

Capturing groups:

Red: value of red
Green: value of green,
Blue: value of blue

---

```
match = re.search(r"IFCCOLOURRGB\((?P<Red>\.[0-9]{1,16}|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,16})?),(?P<Green>\.[0-9]{1,16}|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,16})?),(?P<Blue>\.[0-9]{1,16}|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,16})?)\)", subject)
if match:
    result1 = match.group("Red")
    result2 = match.group("Green")
    result3 = match.group("Blue")       
else:
    result = ""
```